# Google Earth Engine: Sampling through image collection

Tags: google-earth-engine, features, loop, iteration, sample

I am trying to get samples from each image in an image collection and merge them into a single feature collection. So, I wrote the following code (https://code.earthengine.google.com/6797070d93452804e9e0003233039ad8), but It keeps returning the sample from the first image and avoiding the rest.

Do you have any suggestions?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I used flatten() to merge the features, otherwise, they weren't showing up:

https://code.earthengine.google.com/1198f828bf885142985d41ad19f3b0c3

Comment: Please include a code snippet that illustrates your answer within it.